# Error message: Could not connect to roomba

Tags: ros, roomba-500-series

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I was trying to run the node roomba500_light_node in package roomba_500_series. I have connected the roomba. But it gives me the error message:"could not connect to roomba".
I think I may have missed something in the process. Maybe a driver for roomba500? Could you give me some suggestion regarding how to solve the problem?

Thank you so much!

Regards,
Deb

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48158/error-message:-could-not-connect-to-roomba/) by [deb](https://answers.ros.org/users/3579/deb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-11-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Devasena Inupakutika](https://answers.ros.org/users/4122/devasena-inupakutika/) on 2013-03-02**:
Hi Deb, Could you be able to resolve this error and communicate with roomba ? I am also facing similar problem. Please let me know in case you figured this out.  Thanks, Devasena

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Deb,

1. First check to which USB port your roomba is connected using command:

ls /dev/ttyUSB*

2. Change the permission of that USB port say it's /dev/ttyUSB0...

sudo chmod 777 /dev/ttyUSB0

3. Now try running rosrun:

rosrun roomba_500_series roomba500_light_node

Hope this helps !!

---

Originally posted by [Devasena Inupakutika](https://answers.ros.org/users/4122/devasena-inupakutika/) with karma: 320 on 2013-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1